# How to convert a Swing program into MVC form?

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller

I got source code for making a bar chart from the link given below -

[Bar chart in java](http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/swing/draw-simple-bar-chart.shtml)

I made a model class which stores the items and their corresponding values. Then, I made a panel class which is supposed to only take the model and display it as a bar chart. Then I made a frame class which adds the panel to its content pane. Then, I made a driver class which is supposed to run all this, exactly like the code given in the link.

The problem is that I see only my frame and no bar chart. How can I fix it?

I have purposely not included my code because it will be too big. But, if you feel that I should put it here, then please tell me.

```
package myArea;

public class SimpleBarChartModel{

private String[] items;
private double[] valuesOfItems;
private String title;

public SimpleBarChartModel(String[] itemList, double[] valueList, String title){

    String[] items = itemList;
    double[] valuesOfItems = valueList;

}

public String[] getItems(){
    return items;
}

public void setItems(String[] items){
    this.items = items;
}

public double[] getValuesOfItems(){
    return valuesOfItems;
}

public void setValuesOfItems(double[] valuesOfItems){
    this.valuesOfItems = valuesOfItems;
}

public String getTitle(){
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title){
    this.title = title;
}


}


package myArea;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SimpleBarChartPanel extends JPanel{

SimpleBarChartModel bChartMdl; 

public SimpleBarChartPanel(SimpleBarChartModel bcMdl){

    bChartMdl = bcMdl; 

}

public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {

//Must always be the first line in paintComponent method
super.paintComponent(graphics);
double[] values = bChartMdl.getValuesOfItems();
String[] items = bChartMdl.getItems();
String title = bChartMdl.getTitle();     

if (values == null || values.length == 0)
return;

double minValue = 0;
double maxValue = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (minValue > values[i]){

        minValue = values[i];
    }

    if (maxValue < values[i]){

        maxValue = values[i];
    }

}

Dimension dim = getSize();
int clientWidth = dim.width;
int clientHeight = dim.height;
int barWidth = clientWidth / values.length;
Font titleFont = new Font("Book Antiqua", Font.BOLD, 15);
FontMetrics titleFontMetrics = graphics.getFontMetrics(titleFont);
Font labelFont = new Font("Book Antiqua", Font.PLAIN, 10);
FontMetrics labelFontMetrics = graphics.getFontMetrics(labelFont);
int titleWidth = titleFontMetrics.stringWidth(title);
int q = titleFontMetrics.getAscent();
int p = (clientWidth - titleWidth) / 2;
graphics.setFont(titleFont);
graphics.drawString(title, p, q);
int top = titleFontMetrics.getHeight();
int bottom = labelFontMetrics.getHeight();

if (maxValue == minValue){
    return;
}


double scale = (clientHeight - top - bottom) / (maxValue - minValue);
q = clientHeight - labelFontMetrics.getDescent();
graphics.setFont(labelFont);

for (int j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
    int valueP = j * barWidth + 1;
    int valueQ = top;
    int height = (int) (values[j] * scale);

    if (values[j] >= 0){

        valueQ += (int) ((maxValue - values[j]) * scale);
}else{
        valueQ += (int) (maxValue * scale);
        height = -height;
}

        graphics.setColor(Color.blue);
        graphics.fillRect(valueP, valueQ, barWidth - 2, height);
        graphics.setColor(Color.black);
        graphics.drawRect(valueP, valueQ, barWidth - 2, height);
        int labelWidth = labelFontMetrics.stringWidth(items[j]);
        p = j * barWidth + (barWidth - labelWidth) / 2;
        graphics.drawString(items[j], p, q);

    }

}   


}


package myArea;

import javax.swing.*;

public class SimpleBarChartView extends JFrame{

SimpleBarChartPanel bChartPanel;

public SimpleBarChartView(SimpleBarChartPanel bcPanel, int width, int height){

    bChartPanel = bcPanel;
    this.setSize(width, height);
    this.getContentPane().add(bChartPanel);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}

}   


package myArea;

public class SimpleBarChartDriver {

public static void main(String[]args){

    double[] value= new double[5];
    String[] languages = new String[5];

    value[0] = 1;
    languages[0] = "Visual Basic";

    value[1] = 2;
    languages[1] = "PHP";

    value[2] = 3;
    languages[2] = "C++";

    value[3] = 4;
    languages[3] = "C";

    value[4] = 5;
    languages[4] = "Java";

            SimpleBarChartModel sBModel = 
            new SimpleBarChartModel(languages,value,"comp languages");
    SimpleBarChartPanel sBPanel = new SimpleBarChartPanel(sBModel);
    SimpleBarChartView sbView = new SimpleBarChartView(sBPanel, 500, 500);
    sbView.setVisible(true);    
}

}
```

**UPDATE - These are the errors i get when i run the driver class**

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.stringWidth(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: You don't get to control the votes of others.

Comment: *"Then, I made a panel class which is supposed to only take the model and display it as a bar chart."*  OK.  Though why extend panel rather than just use an instance of one?  *"I got source code for making a bar chart from the link given below -   http://www.roseindia.noooo..... please tell me. Don't down vote me."*   If someone were to down-vote, it would more likely be for asking to fix or look at code that originated from RoseIndia (or for daring to direct their actions).

Comment: I fear that your post as currently presented it is unanswerable because you haven't supplied enough information to allow us to understand the problem. You ask us about misbehaving code, and yet we see no code. Your best bet is to isolate your problem first, and then short of solving it, present the offending code. Else this question will likely be closed.

Comment: @SuperStar - Absolutely not. What part of "you do not get to control the votes of others" do you not understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are shadowing variables in a class:

```
class SimpleBarChartModel {
   private String[] items;
   private double[] valuesOfItems;
   private String title;

   public SimpleBarChartModel(String[] itemList, double[] valueList,
         String title) {
      String[] items = itemList; // **** here
      double[] valuesOfItems = valueList;  // **** here
   }
```

Where indicated above you are redeclaring class fields, and so the actual fields will remain as nulls. The solution is not to re-declare the fields but to use the class fields:

```
class SimpleBarChartModel {
   private String[] items;
   private double[] valuesOfItems;
   private String title;

   public SimpleBarChartModel(String[] itemList, double[] valueList,
         String title) {
      items = itemList; // **** here
      valuesOfItems = valueList;  // **** here

      // !! missing something else here !! ;-)
   }
```

Next when you get your NullPointerException, check the line that throws the exception. One of the variables has not been initialized, and you must correct your code so that it becomes initialized.

Comment: Oh silly me :( I fixed that error. But, now I get a Nulll pointer exception. I mentioned it in my question now. please help me to fix it.

Comment: @SuperStar: Oh silly you, I already mentioned the NPE in my answer and gave a hint as to its solution in my second code block.

Comment: DUHHHHH.... :( Why do i make such stupid errors :( Thanks hovercraft...maybe i need to put my head in a bucket full of eels :P